# Yahoo's finance data for dividends is flat out wrong for CBA.AX. Why is that?

Tags: dividends, australia, shares, yahoo-finance

I looked the the dividend history for CBA.AX

https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBA.AX/history?period1=686152800&period2=1525010400&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d

and I went to the CBA website and found a completely different set of numbers!

https://www.commbank.com.au/about-us/shareholders/managing-your-shares/dividend.html

For example, the dividend for the half year ending 31 Dec 2017 is shown by CBA as $2 but Yahoo shows $2.8571.

Yahoo's numbers are different. Why is that?

Answer (score 7):

Atypically, Yahoo appears to show a grossed-up dividend (i.e. the dividend, adjusted for franking credits) rather than the actual dividend paid to a shareholder.

As at 30 Apr 2018, Yahoo shows a dividend for Date 14 Feb 2018 of $2.8571.

Commonwealth Bank (CBA) actually paid a $2 dividend, fully franked.  Australia's company tax rate is currently 30%.  Therefore, the grossed-up dividend is $2 * franking rate/ (100%-30%) = 2 * 100% / (100%-30%) = 2*1/0.7 = $2.857142857

The Australian Taxation Office has a lot of information regarding franking credits/franked dividends:
https://www.ato.gov.au/Business/Imputation/Receiving-dividends-and-other-distributions/